# Formula to estimate time to build SCSF-CAB / WPF-Composite

Tags: estimation, scsf

In my company management is looking for screen-pumping-machine/production-line-factory for data centric (form entry) windows apps. And I am for the task to build the tool that should automate the estimations given the technical requirements.

I am trying to build a formula to estimate time to build web apps (ASPNET MVC, etc).  Since the break-down activity list is kind of standard.

I wanted to know if someone out there had to build a tool like this for making his/her estimations before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no silver bullet when it comes to work time estimations in the SE world.

You can do a gut-check based on your own capabilities and the time it took you to do similar things, but that's about it. You can track metrics on project/work time and attempt to  extrapolate, but you'll need really good data to do any good projections.

Comment: I understand, but one of the benefits of software factories is that it addresses that problem by using proven practices for developing specific style of application and integrated guidance that are easy for project teams to adopt. In our case we are producing the same kind of applications (outlook-like) over and over.

Comment: In that case, estimate the time it should take to build a foundational library that you can cookie-cutter for your outlook-like applications. Then estimate the time to customize that foundation for each application. 

But again, there's no silver bullet, no magic formula. It's 100% subjective.